# Insert data from MySQL or PHP in Powerpoint

Tags: php, mysql, powerpoint

On an event I have a powerpoint presentation running continuously.

Is there a way to update slides of this presentation automatically with data from a MySQL database or through a website?

Comment: You might be better off running an online presentation continuously and changing this.

Comment: It might be better to have a full-screen web page in a browser, and then you don't have to worry about VBA and horrible Microsoft things, and you can use whatever you want (Ruby + Sinatra, PHP, whatever) to run the screen.

Comment: You'll find it difficult to embed anything directly into a running powerpoint presentation, as that entails a PHP script that can directly affect the running of a MS application... I'm not certain if there are even any MS tools that would allow that

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can conenct to the MySQL database thru ODBC and a short VBA script.

See [this example](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?331453-Using-ODBC-in-VBA-%28Excel%29).

You can use `Connection String`, that way the parameters (like server's name username password) can reside inside your file and there will be no external dependencies. (You don't need to create a *datasource*).

**Security considerations**

I recommend creating a distinct user for this purpose and a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which would be visible to this user. - This way if someone gets the credentials out of the file could not do something malicious.

On another note: share this only with friendly users (like employees of the same company) on a LAN or VPN. MySQL servers are not usually open to the wide world especially not with a public user/pass.